# OpenGL log file (MESA)

Tags: graphics, log, opengl

Recently my firefox started to freeze I have a strong feeling that it has to do something with opengl, but I can't prove it, because I can't find any opengl or mesa log file. And yes I looked at `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old` but except backtrace I wasn't able to find anything else about the error.

Where can I find some log files that logs everything graphics related?

Comment: Why do you think it is openGL related? Did you try another browser with the same sites causing Firefox to freeze? Did you try clearing Firefox cache?

Comment: It started after updating my intel graphic driver, also in Xorg log there is something. I have read about this error also on mac and windows, all caused by opengl, however the bug has to be in firefox not handling something well(that's why I need that log, to see what exactly is not handled well) because I have tried another browser and also clearing the cache.

Answer (score 0):

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log` is for X Window system level log.

For application log, or application related X Windows error, try `~/.xsessiion-error`.